# autotools: defining a variable for test script

Tags: autotools

How I would define a variable in configure.ac so that it would be accessible in bash test script?

To be concrete, I would like to pass a variable which specifies width of word on current host (32 or 64).

Comment: I tried AC_SUBST with no luck, I don't know why it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

I found answer: need to set TESTS_ENVIRONMENT in Makefile.am to pass variable to test script.